# How to detect that Preference is exist or not in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have created an android app, in that I want to check that the preference is exist or not.

My code is:

```
public static boolean checkPref(Context context, String name)
{   
    SharedPreference sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String uid = sharedPreferences.getString(name, "n/a");

    if(uid!= null && !uid.equals(""))
    {   
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
public static boolean checkPref(Context context, String name)
{   
    SharedPreference sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPreferences.contains(name);             
}
```

Comment: it always returns false.

Comment: It will work. The documentation says so: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

if a sharedPreference doesn't exist a NullPointerException will be thrown, so I recommend you manage your code like this :

```
try
{
   //handle the situation where there exists the shared preference
}

catch(NullPointerException exc)
{
    //handle the situation of non-existent sharedpreference 
}
```